# Formulation of an xpath query?

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

Hey,
I have a html page which contains for example the following tags :

```
<p foruri="http://doc.scrapy.org/getting-help:solving-specific-problems" rec="lang.en" id="solving-specific-problems">Hello world!!! From my authoring tool.</p>

<p foruri="http://doc.scrapy.org/getting-help:getting help" rec="lang.en" id="getting help">Hello world!!! From my authoring tool.</p>
```

Now I wrote a crawler using the scrapy framework in python,in which i used the cxxpath query to find the foruri tag as `//@foruri` which should give me the `foruri` tag where ever it is present, but the problem is it does not yield http:

So help me in getting it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you wish to extract the *foruri* attribute of all <p> tags:

```
hxs.select('//p/@foruri').extract()
```